# What is our take on list-style community-wiki questions?

Tags: discussion, community-wiki

I have asked a [question about devops conferences](https://devops.stackexchange.com/q/504/46) around the world. And it has been closed as a list question, whereas it has been a helpful post in both [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/1904/statistics-conferences) and [DataScience](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/q/8941/11097).

As it would be converted to a community-wiki, I don't see the problem with it being a list question.

A [user also mentioned](https://devops.stackexchange.com/questions/504/devops-conferences/505#comment807_504) that this would be too long for a list question, but I don't see the down side of it. What is wrong if the list of answers is too long, if it's helping the users.  Also, when the users can flag and vote on answers, I don't think it'll be difficult to maintain such community wikis, esp Devops is turning out to being an active private beta.

Comment: The Community Wiki feature has been largely deprecated and has already  been removed from the 'Ask Question' page. Even as a special setting, Community Wiki should *not* be used to forgive questions that otherwise would not be allowed.

Comment: @RobertCartaino My reasoning behind the CW question was to have a one post only everyone could edit to keep it up to date. But for this specific case, it may not fit within the post limit anyway.

Comment: @Tensibai That particular use case for Community Wiki was replaced by the 'suggested edit'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Quoting a [relevant answer](https://sustainability.meta.stackexchange.com/a/129/99) from SE community moderator Robert Cartaino on a similar question on a different SE site:

> The problem with most of these "let's create a list" questions is that it becomes really hard to begrudge anyone their entry. Voting on a favorite book/tool/application/website/blog/etc is based on popularity and what you know, and all semblance of expertise is lost. These questions are fine for a roundtable discussion forum; but for a Q&A site, we generally suggest forgoing them completely.
>
> I can appreciate the desire to ask these "getting started primers" — It's just easier to cast a broad net and pick through the random answers to see what suits your particular interests later. But this site will work better if you help users flesh out a question about what specific problem they are encountering and what they are having trouble understanding in their day to day work. Specific, long-tailed questions will work much better than "you guys talk and I'll pick out the good stuff later."

This being said, I do think there is a use for (community-wiki) list-questions, but only if such a question:

1. is focused on a particular problem
2. has an answer with a limited number of entries (say less than 25)
3. the answers aren't changing / outdated quickly

Your example question fails on all 3 points.

Comment: Fully agree with this position, and  7ochem's comment give a very good reason to keep it closed finally.