# How to properly ask questions with geographical limitations?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

How do you ask question about resources that could have a geographical limitations? For example questions on Conferences, Seminars, University programs, etc.

Questions like that can either be viewed as too broad, because they would have many different answers for each region or they could be viewed as too narrow and excluding part of the community if restricted to a specific region. Do we simply avoid all such questions, unless the resources are available online?

Would this mean we need to exclude a large part of this subtopic?

Comment: I indeed do think they are not a good fit for this kind of site. (not an answer  at all to how to ask them, so just a comment to voice the position)

Comment: There is a concept in databases called partitioning, when a data set is too large, it can be partitioned along ranges on a specific index. Is it really not possible in any way to partition a question with some geographic specificity into a set of questions that would each be relevant and together form a complete picture?

Comment: The problem is agreeing on what is a reasonable scope geographically I think to avoid getting a question for each town over 50k inhabitants. This can be tested when we will have more people able to moderate answers to get rid of spam for each existing conference/learning site, etc

Answer (score 3):

There may be some cases where geographically-constrained questions make sense. For example if you have to follow certain rules or laws that only apply to a particular country/region. I can't think of a good example right now for DevOps, but we have a several of those questions on Sustainability SE for example (which is also why that site has country tags).

However asking for resources is often off-topic (see my answer to the meta question: [What is our take on list-style community-wiki questions?](https://devops.meta.stackexchange.com/a/102/460))

Comment: Here's an example: [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation)-related questions, IMHO with some devops-related implications

Answer (score 0):

**I don't think they'd be a good fit in SE.**

Why?

Cause, if they get on-topic, how do we define a Geographical boundary?  Will it be a continent, specific area, country, city, or a place?

So, it's difficult, and often confusing come to a consensus with.

However, questions with an overall view, and to-the-point are on-topic.

Like for example: `What are the annual container-tech related conferences?`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The examples you gave for Geography based questions are also very limited in terms of Time.

Conferences, Seminars, University programs, etc, all change from Year to year and can exist for a very short amount of time.

On the other hand, people often travel across the globe to attend a specific University or Conferences, so I don't really think the question is limited to a specific geography.